# Ignoring errors when Converting Characters to Date

Tags: r, date, format

I have a Character Column that primarily contains dates in a DateNum pattern (e.g. 41269, 44294, 43057 etc). Unfortunately, due to a lack of validation at the source there are also some erroneous value in there, such as "-" or "03/012025"

I am trying to convert these into a standard date, while ignoring the invalid values. I don't want to lose the rows containing the data but I am happy to lose the value or replace it with NA

At the moment I have tried 2 methods to achieve this but have not been able to to get either to work properly

My approach at the moment is to find a way to only format those values that are Numeric, rather than havign to list all of the invalid characters (as the ones mentioned above may not cover all of them)

To this end I have been using the following code:

```
transformed_data$Expiry_Date<-format(as.Date(transformed_data$Expiry_Date ,optional=TRUE, tryFormats = "", origin="1899-12-30"))
```

However I do not seem able to find an example of the format to include in tryFormats that would only format Numeric values. All examples I have found so far refer to specific DDMMYY formats

I also looked at using NA_IF to cleanse the data before formatting it as a date (see below)

```
transformed_data$Expiry_Date<-na_if(transformed_data$Expiry_Date, is.numeric(transformed_data$Expiry_Date))
```

However, this does not appear to have any effect on the results.

I would like the values that are currently in a DateNum style to be displayed as a date, and any invalid data to be replaced by NA (or left blank)

As suggested here is a code snippet that produces illustrates the problem.

```
x <- c("41269","-","44294","03/012025","43057")
y<-format(as.Date(as.integer(x), origin="1899-12-30"))
```

The above includes the suggested change by @Rohit to include "as.integer". While this works it also generates a warning "NAs introduced by coercion"

Comment: I assume your date column is of character type due to the erroneous data. Try first doing  `as.integer` before `as.Date`. That should directly replace the wrong entries with `NA`. Also, if your date format is number of days from `origin`, then you need to convert it to numeric anyway

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: @Rohit as.integer works but it also generates the following error message "NAs introduced by coercion". Is there anything I can do to resolve this or does it not really cause a problem?

Comment: @RonakShah I will have a go at creating a reproducible example and update my post once done. Thanks

Comment: @paulandjules The warning's just informing you that some NAs have been generated. Since it's what you want, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Rohit Thanks. If that's the case then your solution works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Rohit I have included "as.integer" to achieve the desired output, using the following code:

```
x <- c("41269","-","44294","03/012025","43057")
y<-format(as.Date(as.integer(x), origin="1899-12-30"))
```

While this produces a warning regarding "NAs introduced by coercion" this does not impact the outcome. If desired I can also use suppressWarnings to prevent the warning being displayed (see below)

```
y<-suppressWarnings(format(as.Date(as.integer(x), origin="1899-12-30")))
```

Thanks for helping me resolve this matter